# Select * From Table Where column=data is not working

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am using SQL Server. The following query is working fine:

```
select * 
from Users 
where Users.Id = 1
```

but when I use

```
select * 
from Users 
where Users.Username = "User"
```

this does not work.

Error:

> Invalid Column name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use on quote instead of double quote

```
select * from Users where Users.Username = 'User'
```

`text` datatype has been deprecated, you need to change the datatype to `VARCHAR(n)/NVARCHAR(n)` as it depends on your data and your needs.

Comment: still Error -The data types text and varchar are incompatible in the equal to operator.

Comment: Does `Username` column is `TEXT` datatype?

Comment: yes it is a text type

Comment: Change the datatype then @MuhammadAbdullah. `text` has been deprecated for 14 years. I also doubt you need 2GB worth of characters (that's over 2 Billion characters) to store a user's username.

Comment: what should i use

Comment: @MuhammadAbdullah You need to ALTER your table and change the datatype, as Larnu already said.

Comment: What datatype nvarchar(50)?

Comment: It depends on your needs, if you going to store unicode chars or not, also the lenght needed

Comment: depends how many characters you need to store the data, and if you need unicode characters. If the username can be up to 15 characters, and only contains ASCII characters, then use a `varchar(15)`. if it could be up to 50 characters, and include unicode character, use an `nvarchar(50)`. You know your data better than us; as we don't know it at all.

Comment: I am making a simple login form and first time using sql server